# Control a wince device from desktop

Tags: windows-ce

I would like to know if there is a tool simillar to mymobiler for Wince 5.0 which I can use to control the device from my desktop. 
I use mymobiler (v1.25) but I believe it controls only devices running on WM5 and above.

Any help would be highly apprecited as the screen of my device has stopped working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use MyMobiler myself when I am coding for WinCE5.0 (not very often but I do know that it works.)

In your extracted MyMobiler zip file is three versions of remote.exe.

1. remote.exe
2. remote.exe.50
3. remote.exe.40

The only one I have gotten to work on wince5 is remote.exe.40

Just rename the existing remote.exe file (remote.exe.wm) [you may have to click tools, folder options, and uncheck hide extensions for known file types]

Next rename remote.exe.40 to remote.exe.

After that you are good to go. Copy remote.exe to the device through activesync (xp) or WMDC (>XP) and launch it on the device. It was a bit funny connecting for me the first time - I click connect on pc, then had to click the tray icon on the device, and click connect.

Good Luck!

Link to Video Showing it Running [1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYFBECTrrG4)

Answer (score 3):

This does work, the auto-install doesn't seem to work but if you copy the remote.exe over as mentioned (any location will do), then start remote.exe, click on the MYMobiler icon in the tray and select Connect, it will attach to your PC like the WinMobile version does.

Also, check the ini files in the MyMobiler directory. There's some details on the features/options.

Comment: I cannot get it work on [Motorola MC3190 device running Windows CE 6.0.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982772/remote-control-wince-6-0-device). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Dave and Mike's solutions work on **Windows CE 7** as well.
I was getting an error with the `AYGSHELL.dll` library when starting My Mobile after the gun was connected.

Run `Mymobiler.exe` before you connect the scanner to the PC and then connect to the PC using the tray icon from the gun. No error.